# Unable to figure out the error from trailblazer

Tags: javascript, trailhead, certification, summer-22

Friends,

I am trying to complete my "javascript developer 1 certification maintenance summer 22" hands-on requirement. I think I have done as requested in the task below :

*Get Hands-On with New Alert, Confirm, and Prompt modules and components.
Create a new Lightning Web component
Name: recordCardQuickFiles
Import LightningConfirm from "lightning/confirm"
Replace the confirm method with the LightningConfirm method
Message: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?"
Variant: "headerless"
Label: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?"*

However, when I try to validate the challenge, I'm hit with the error "*Please make sure the prework is configured in the playground.*" . I have checked at length on what is the prework required, but no answers found. I posted the same query on trailhead community as well, still no luck (got some weird advices like enable/disable permission set groups in User management setting) . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Struggled a bit but then I found the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658945/problem-with-trailhead-get-hands-on-with-new-alert-confirm-and-prompt-modules

It seems as though the messaging etc. is very specific:

```
        const confirmation = LightningConfirm.open({
            Message: 'Are you sure you want to delete all files?',
            Variant: 'headerless',
            Label: 'Are you sure you want to delete all files?'
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! As this isn't an asnwer to the question, this will probably be deleted. Normally, if you have a different (but related) question, you would want to create your own question (and link to this one if it helps provide context). In this particular case though, you should double check to make sure you're paying close attention to the instructions. If you still can't find anything wrong, then I think you might be better off going through https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help .